# SetInterval is called 2 times every time

Tags: javascript, create-react-app, setinterval

Here's my app.js

```
import "./App.css";
import Background from "./Background.js";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Background />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

here's my Background.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { seconds } from "./Image.js";
import img from "./images/img.jpg";

class Background extends React.Component {
render() {
        console.log("render called" + " " + seconds().getSeconds());
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log("setIntervall called  " + seconds().getSeconds());
        }, 2000);

        return (
            <div className="background">
                <img src={img} alt="img" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Background;
```

here seconds is just returning "new Date()"

and this is the console output
[image]

Why is setInterval called 2 times every time?

Comment: You should probably clear this interval when your component is unmounted.

Comment: If you're using strict mode, it might be related to this - https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9

Comment: understood thanks!